# Match HTTP requests that are missing some header

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Suppose I have following redirection in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /pl/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L]
```

How can I extend it, so requests missing Accept-Language header will be redirected to /pl/ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to switch the order of your rules to make the `/pl` one the default:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /pl/ [L]
```

So if someone has specifically an accept language of `en`, it rewrites to `/en`, otherwise, it gets rewritten to `/pl`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^[a-z]{2}- [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```